# libGDX game crashes on Android without any mention of crash in logs

Tags: libgdx, android

No mention of any issue in process logs, an application just turns off during loading assets (~3% of all assets loaded). It works fine on desktop.

Only thing that seems related in global logs is this:

```
09-01 15:15:25.261 824-22928/? W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{911979f u0 xxx.xxx.xxx/.AndroidLauncher t664}: app died, no saved state
```

I suspect there might not be enough of memory, but why there is nothing in logs? I tried limiting JVM memory on PC to 512MB and it runs fine. But I am not entirely sure if this limit covers also native memory. Could that be the reason why it runs with limit set and yet crashes on a mobile device with 2GB memory?

Answer (score 1):

After splitting textures to multiple atlases and loading them only when needed, application runs fine. So I guess it was caused by lack of memory.